# Why my CoreData entity objects are unknown?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

When I'm building the app I'm getting the following errors for all CoreData object classes:

[image]

I did include CoreData library in `Prefix.pch`. Also, every time when I run build, the number of errors varies from 48 to 62.

It seems Xcode just doesn't recognize that they are defined at all. How should I resolve this?

Here's the header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "Activities.h"

@class Activities;

@interface Projects : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * information;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *activities;
@end

@interface Projects (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addActivitiesObject:(Activities *)value;
- (void)removeActivitiesObject:(Activities *)value;
- (void)addActivities:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeActivities:(NSSet *)values;

+(NSArray*)retrieveProjects;

-(void)setName:(NSString*)name information:(NSString*) information date:(NSDate *) date;

@end
```

And the `.m` file:

```
#import "Projects.h"

@implementation Projects

@dynamic name;
@dynamic information;
@dynamic date;
@dynamic activities;

+(NSArray*)retrieveProjects
{
    //Retrieve all project entries and return as an NSArray here
}

-(void)setName:(NSString*)name information:(NSString*) information date:(NSDate *) date
{
    // Set a Projects object’s attributes;
}

@end
```

Comment: Show one of your object classes. Also, see if they show up assigned to a target when you select them in the file browser.

Comment: @Mundi What do you mean by "if they show up assigned to a target"?

Comment: On the right panel the leftmost tab is the document properties editor. There you should have a list of your targets and a checkmark with every `.m` file that you need to include. Make sure also that you `#include` the custom object classes wherever you need them.

Comment: @Mundi In the `Target Membership` section I only see two checkboxes, one is my project and the other is my project tests. And it is nothing different from the previous commit that builds correctly.

Comment: So please show an object class as requested.

Comment: @Mundi Sorry. See the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting #import "Activities.h" in .m file, maybe its include issue cause U include this .h Activities.h i suppose

Comment: What's the difference between including in .h and .m?

Comment: If U include B.h in class A.h and A.h in B.h than U have recursive includes and the compiler is confused

Comment: So include both classes in .m and do @class Activities; like U did in .h